# Separate Contact from message in notifications text

Tags: android-notifications

I can read text from notifications using

```
CharSequence[] arr = extras.getCharSequenceArray(Notification.EXTRA_TEXT_LINES);

for(CharSequence l:arr)

Log.d("duglas",l.toString());
```

The text i received is of the form :

> 2-25 10:07:00.351  18879-18895/? D/duglas﹕ Idea  Hi
>
> 12-25 10:07:00.351  18879-18895/? D/duglas﹕ Idea  J
>
> 12-25 10:07:00.351  18879-18895/? D/duglas﹕ Idea  G
>
> 12-25 10:07:00.351  18879-18895/? D/duglas﹕ Idea  Hi
>
> 12-25 10:07:00.351  18879-18895/? D/duglas﹕ Idea  N
>
> 12-25 10:07:00.351  18879-18895/? D/duglas﹕ Testnotify  Hi

Now from the above text I need to separate messages like "Hi" from contact like "Idea".

Is it possible?

I have tried

```
  extras.get(Notification.EXTRA_PEOPLE);
```

But it doesn't lists all contacts in the notification.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although Notification.EXTRA_PEOPLE in the extras of the notification object can be used to relate people to notifications but it is not necessary that all the contacts linked to a notification must be present in that field. So, it is highly dependent upon how the notification is being built and hence not possible to list contacts in every notification.That's why it is difficult to separate contact from notification text efficiently simply  by manipulating the text.

Answer (score 0):

Get your answer into a `string array`.

```
String[] = myString.split("\\s+");
```

First try this with a Single string contains more the one white spaces then find a way your to use this into you Project.

Comment: The probable problem with split approach is that the messages can be of form - Sender Name Message. In such strings it will be difficult to decide whether to include "Name" in message or sender's name. So the solution i am looking for is to somehow retrieve contacts in a notification to distinguish that string from message portion.

Comment: Please update your code so i can help you more to resolve your issue